# Accessing Azure Table storage from React

Tags: reactjs, azure

I'm looking at accessing data from Azure Table Storage and Azure Blob storage from a React app. The examples I am seeing all show using a SAS, which makes me nervous because of it being available on the client-side. We are also authenticating using Azure AD, so is there a client API available that will allow me to query Azure Table Storage and Blob Storage using AD authentication, similar to how I use Microsoft Graph API to query AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so is there a client API available that will allow me to query Azure
>   Table Storage and Blob Storage using AD authentication, similar to how
>   I use Microsoft Graph API to query AD?

For Table Storage, Azure AD authentication/authorization is not yet supported and you will have to use SAS URL at least as of now.

For Blob Storage (as well as Queue Storage), Azure AD authentication/authorization is indeed supported. This was announced quite some time ago and I believe all the client SDKs have support for that. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad.

You would still need to configure CORS rule properly to connect to a storage account from a React App (or for that matter any JavaScript based client side app).

Comment: Thank you. I read that but assumed Table Storage might have already been released but was old news.